# Force Download an Audio Stream

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an audio stream from an external server and am not able perform any serverside changes. It currently works pretty well but it's only able to stream the songs in an HTML5 audio element. I'd also like to implement a download feature, the problem is, a link doesn't download anything, it automatically streams the mp3. The HTML5 download attribute doesn't do anything.

The complete Response Headers by the server:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection:close
Content-Length:6991749
Content-Type:audio/mpeg
Date:Sun, 28 Apr 2013 19:40:49 GMT
Expires:Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified:Thu, 10 Jan 2013 18:59:31 GMT
Server:nginx/1.0.2
```

It should work completely in JavaScript, if possible without PHP proxy.

Comment: are you hotlinking or something?

Comment: I'm streaming from http://grooveshark.com or what did you wanted to know? (my english is not the best, sorry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it now,
the problem was, that the server automatically refused access to the temporary created Stream URI when it was requested once. I just commented out the HTML5 audio element and only placed an download link with the new HTML5 Download attribute

```
<a href="stream.com/stream.mp3" download="filename.mp3">
```

If i would not have set the "download" attribute, the browser would have automatically streamed the file.
Thumbs up to HTML5!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my initial pessimism (about this being impossible) might have misguided.  Here is a demo that makes use of some of the HTML5 File API (not as advanced as some of the stuff I've been reading about, but it seems security limitations make totally automating this a bit out of reach at the moment, [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6jb5g/19/) works in Firefox and Chrome but I would guess only IE10 could stand a chance at supporting it.

```
var createObjectURL = function (file) {
    if (window.webkitURL) {
        return window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(file);
    } else if (window.URL && window.URL.createObjectURL) {
        return window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
},
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/63/Wikipedia-logo.png', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function (e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        var url = createObjectURL(new Blob([this.response], {
            type: 'image/png'
        }));
        var link = document.createElement('A');
        link.setAttribute('href', url);
        link.setAttribute('Download', 'Name I Want it to have.png');
        link.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Download'));
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(link);

    }
};
xhr.send();
```

Here I am using `XMLHttpRequest` to request a PNG, then I'm storing it in a `Blob` and creating a download URL with some extra information that triggers the browser to download the asset instead of just linking to it (which is what it would do with a PNG).  I couldn't find a Grooveshark URL that didn't require some session key, so I don't know if this will work for you, but that limitation comes from Groovshark's efforts to prevent hot linking to songs.

Comment: Thanks, looks pretty nice! The problem is, that the page also doesn't allow me any XMLhttpRequests because of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin rule. Maybe Flash will do it? EDIT: It works now, the HTML5 Download attribute was very helpful, will write my own answer!